# Two uniform random variables with a distance smaller than 1

Tags: probability

Let's say we have $X,Y\sim Uni(0,10)$. I would suppose $P(|y-x|<1)=1\cdot \frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{10}$, because for any given value $X$ gets, the wanted values are $1/10$ of the total length $Y$ can get. But if we are looking at it graphically ($|y-x|<1$):
[image]

And calculating the pink region, it is $19/100$ of the whole $10\times10$ square. Why do I receive different answers?

Comment: Think what happens when $Y$ and $X$ are close to $0$ or $10$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any value $X$ it is NOT true that the wanted values for $Y$ are $\dfrac{1}{10}$ the size of the range of $Y$. Here are a few examples:

If $X = 5$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs when $4 < Y < 6$ which has a probability of $\dfrac{2}{10}$ not $\dfrac{1}{10}$.

If $X = \dfrac{1}{2}$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs when $0 \le Y < \dfrac{3}{2}$ which has a probability of $\dfrac{3}{20}$ not $\dfrac{1}{10}$.

If $X = 0$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs when $0 \le Y < 1$ which does have a probability of $\dfrac{1}{10}$.

In general, if $X = x$ with $0 \le x \le 1$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs for $0 \le Y \le x+1$. If $X = x$ with $1 \le x \le 9$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs for $x-1 \le Y \le x+1$. If $X = x$ with $9 \le x \le 10$, then $|Y-X| < 1$ occurs for $x-1 \le Y \le 10$. You can see these facts visually by drawing a vertical line in your picture.